# Newton-Raphson in C

Tags: c

I am writing a program to find an approximation of the square root of a given integer n using the Newton-Raphson method in C. I have used the following formula:

[image: newton-raphson iteration]

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

double newton_raphson(int n, int iter);

double newton_raphson(int n, int iter)
{
    if(iter == 0) // base case
        return 1;
    else // iterative case
        return (1/2*(newton_raphson(n, iter-1) + n/(newton_raphson(n, iter-1))));
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    int i;

    printf("Enter a number you want to know the square root of:\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter number of iterations to be worked out:\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &i);

    printf("%.3f", newton_raphson(n,i-1));

    return 0;
}
```

When I input 2 and 3, and the output expected is 1.417 (the square root of 2 after 3 iterations) I get the error -1.#IO. When I input 5 and 2 for example, I get 0.000. I have debugged it but still can't really figure out what the problem is. Any help is greatly appreciated.

edit: elaborated on the output

Comment: Change `1/2` to `1.0/2.0` to force the use of doubles (or use 0.5)

Comment: You forgot a few things.   Most obvious is what inputs you entered, without which we cannot reproduce your problem.

Comment: You have ints everywhere int(1/2)=0 for example.

Comment: Perhaps change `n/...` to `(double)n/...`

Comment: You'll need to debug this yourself a bit deeper, or at least increase the information you include here: is that the *full* output? or is there something printed before or after? What's your input? Can't you add a few more `printf`s to figure out exactly what works and what not?

Comment: @MartinJames when I enter 2 and 3 I get the error mentioned, however when I enter 5 and 2 for example I simply get 0.000 as output

Comment: The int vs. float issue aside, you call `newton_raphson` recursively twice with the same parameters, which will result in much more calls than you need. Call it once and store the result in a variable, then operate on that. You could render the algorithm as a loop instead of using recursion, too.

Comment: @MOehm could you please elaborate on 'you call newton_raphson recursively twice with the same parameters, which will result in much more calls than you need'?

Comment: @StefaniaDamato : it's horribly inefficient, and it's something that your lecturer should notice and give you less points. What you have here is the rough equivalent of `int fib(int n) { if(n >= 2) return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2); }`, if that helps visualize it.

Comment: Put a print statement at the beginning of the Newton-Raphsen function and you'll see that for thee iterations, you call the function seven times. In general, you call the function 2^iter - 1 times. The second call is redundant, because it evaluates the same data again. The upshot is that [formulas are pretty](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130508-00/?p=4423/), but you usually can't type them out in code verbatim to get what you want.

Comment: @MOehm oh that's right, it is, thank you for pointing it out!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue seems to be that you are mishandling floating point arithmetic.

1. The first argument of the `newton_raphson` function should be a `double`, especially because you seem to be calling it recursively. As it is right now, you just cast the result of one iteration into an integer and pass that to the next iteration.
2. `1 / 2` uses integer arithmetic. That should be `0.5` or `1.0 / 2.0` instead. Note that in integer arithmetic, `1 / 2` is `0`. The error you see is because then you pass that `0` to the next iteration and then it divides by `0`.

## The fixed code

```
#include <stdio.h>

double newton_raphson(double n, int iter);

double newton_raphson(double n, int iter)
{
    if (iter == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0.5 * (newton_raphson(n, iter - 1) + n/(newton_raphson(n, iter - 1)));
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    int i;

    printf("Enter a number you want to know the square root of:\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter number of iterations to be worked out:\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &i);

    printf("%.3f\n", newton_raphson(n, i - 1));

    return 0;
}
```

## Possible improvements

As others pointed out in the comments, you could make this implementation more efficient.

First, you can eliminate a function call by saving the result in a variable. Since this is a recursive function, this will save you a **lot** of execution time if you have many iterations.

```
double newton_raphson(double n, int iter)
{
    if (iter == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        double xk = newton_raphson(n, iter - 1);
        return 0.5 * (xk + n / xk);
    }
}
```

Then, you could eliminate recursion alltogether. This will make your program consume much less memory if you run with many iterations because you get rid of unnecessary stack operations.

```
double newton_raphson(double n, int iter)
{
    int k;
    double xk = 1;
    for (k = 0; k < iter; k++) {
        xk = 0.5 * (xk + n / xk);
    }
    return xk;
}
```

## Some more tips

For the iteration count, you should use `unsigned int` (or simply `unsigned`) instead of `int`. It does not make sense to run a negative number of iterations, eg. you can't run `-5` iterations... so you do not need a signed integer there.

```
#include <stdio.h>

double newton_raphson(double n, unsigned iter);

double newton_raphson(double n, unsigned iter)
{
    unsigned k;
    double xk = 1;
    for (k = 0; k < iter; k++) {
        xk = 0.5 * (xk + n / xk);
    }
    return xk;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    unsigned i;

    printf("Enter a number you want to know the square root of:\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("Enter number of iterations to be worked out:\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%u", &i);

    printf("%.3f\n", newton_raphson(n, i - 1));

    return 0;
}
```

Few more things:

- It is usually a good practice to protect your code from possible division by zero errors, by checking the parameters of your functions or the results of function calls that can possibly return zero.
- You should possibly check the input for negative numbers and tell the user that a negative number isn't something you can calculate the square root of with this algorithm.
- For the input, you could allow the user to enter a floating point number instead of an integer.

Comment: considering floating point division is expensive, a more practical approach is to calculate inverse squire root first then multiply to get squire root.